# jQuery need help to navigate/highligt elements on a complex list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, highlighting

this is my hmtl list.

```
<div class="bradius3 taggy-beans">
    <div class="taggy-beans-search"><input type="text" id="search-tags" class="bradiusMax" style=""></div>
    <div class="pajinate-content">
    <ul class="pajinate">
    <li class="page1" style="display: inline;">
    <ul class="filtered-tags">
    <li><a id="4e72858ccaa47ca608510000" class="bradiusMax bean" href="javascript:void(0)">hey</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page1" style="display: inline;">
    <ul class="filtered-tags">
    <li>
    <a id="4e72858ccaa47ca6082d0000" class="bradiusMax bean" href="javascript:void(0)">hi</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page1" style="display: inline;">
    <ul class="filtered-tags">
    <li>
    <a id="4e72858ccaa47ca6082d0000" class="bradiusMax bean" href="javascript:void(0)">jhon</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

my js script.

```
    $('#search-tags').live('keydown',function(e){
 var $prev, $next, $current = $(".pajinate a.highlight");

    if (e.which === 40 && !$current.length) {
        $(".pajinate a:first").addClass("highlight");
    } else if (e.which === 39) {
        console.log($next);
        $next = $current.next(".pajinate a");
        if ($next.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $next.addClass("highlight");
        }

    } else if (e.which === 37) {
        console.log($prev);
        $prev = $current.prev(".pajinate a");
        if ($prev.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $prev.addClass("highlight");
        }
    } else if (e.which === 38) {
        $(".pajinate a").removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

what i'm trying to do is to navigate by e.keyCode in the html list above, trying highlighting a.bean elements but the script highlights only the first a.bean, then key left or right doesn't highlights a elements

any suggest?

here is an example of the script logic: http://jsfiddle.net/WeNdW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're trying to highlight a elements, you would be too deep in the DOM tree for `next` to work properly. `next` gets the next sibling, and a doesn't have any.

a is highlighted and is set to be `$current`

so `$next` and `$prev` need to go a few levels up the DOM tree in order to get to the true next a

Thus, the part that says `parent().parent().parent()` to go the appropriate amount up the DOM structure. Similarly, `children().children().children()` to go back down and highlight the a.

```
$("#search-tags").live("keydown", function(e) {
    var $prev, $next, $current = $(".pajinate a.highlight");

    if (e.which === 40 && !$current.length) {
        $(".pajinate li:first a").addClass("highlight");
    } else if (e.which === 39) {
        $next = $current.parent().parent().parent().next("li");
        if ($next.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $next.children('ul').children('li').children('a').addClass("highlight");
        }

    } else if (e.which === 37) {
        $prev = $current.parent().parent().parent().prev("li");
        if ($prev.length) {
            $current.removeClass("highlight");
            $prev.children('ul').children('li').children('a').addClass("highlight");
        }
    } else if (e.which === 38) {
        $(".pajinate a.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Litote0707/cSSKg/)

Comment: ops , but i also tested my code with $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){} but doesn't highlights with key right and left :(

Comment: when i play with the fiddle (in firefox 6, fwiw) after a press keydown, the first element is highlighted, then i can use left and right (no down) to move through the elements. once i keyup, nothing is highlighted and so left and right have no effect. is this the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: any reason why the demo highlights li's and the code above tried to highlight a's? if you change the code above to look more like the demo, no problem...

Comment: the demo is for a different type of html list less complex list i mean, and also i would like to highlight <a> not <li> in my code, that example is just to make you understand better the logic of what i would like to do binded to <a> instead

Comment: checked but my html list is different :P as you can see you are using <ul class="pajinate"><li></li><li></li></ul>  while my html is <ul class="pajinate"><ul><li></li></ul><ul><li></li></ul></ul>   :P

Comment: sorry my html is <ul class="pajinate"> <li> <ul> <li><a> highlight</a></li> </ul></li> <li> <ul> <li><a> highlight2</a></li> </ul></li> </ul>

Comment: then just add one more parent/child to `prev`, `next` and `current`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3861/discussion-between-andrea-and-ispuk)